# Regex optional alternative search

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to get some information as groups out of some text using regex.
Desired result is out of the text: `Please check the Health of the JVM=acq855SW1-srv1 Please check the acq855SW1-srv2 profile.It seems like down` to get

- 1st match: Description as '*Please check the Health of the
  JVM=acq855SW1-srv1*' and JVM '*acq855SW1-srv1'*
- 2nd match: Description as "*Please check the acq855SW1-srv2 profile.It seems like down*" and JVM '*acq855SW1-srv2*'

My regex so far is `(?<Description>.*?the (?:JVM=|)(?<JvmName>[^\s]+)(?: profile.*+|))` and I'm trying to avoid the fact that it`s taking also the "Please check the Health" as a match.

[image: Regex]

How can I make in a way that it wont stop at "the Health" ?

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/wesd3J/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Dziekuje!

Comment: Your regex was the easiest to understand, Toto's is effective with the negative look for JVM and Tomasso's nicely explained, working and feels like an answer :)

Comment: Since it proved helpful, I added an [answer with explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60058051/3832970).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy fix is to differentiate `Health` from the others adding the constraint that that value must contain a `-`.

This can be done changing `[^\s]+` to `[^\s]+-[^\s]+`.

So the result regex is:

```regex
(?<Description>.*?the (?:JVM=)?(?<JvmName>[^\s]+-[^\s]+)(?: profile.*+|))
```

[image]

If the `-` is an assumption that cannot be done, you could do the same with numbers.

`[^\s]+\d[^\s]+`

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation Tommaso!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use:

```
(?<Description>(?:(?!JVM=).)*the (?:JVM=)?(?<JvmName>\S+)(?: profile.*+)?)
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/iqXnBU/2)

Answer (score 1):

With PCRE, and some other engines, like Ruby, .NET, PyPi `regex`, you may use several identically named groups and use a pattern like

```
(?<Description>.*?the\s+(?:JVM=(?<JvmName>\S+)|(?<JvmName>\S+)\s+profile.*))
```

To make it work in PCRE, add `(?J)` at the pattern start to enable the feature.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wesd3J/2).

**Details**

- `(?<Description>` - start of `Description` group:

  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
  - `the` - the `the` word
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `(?:JVM=(?<JvmName>\S+)|(?<JvmName>\S+)\s+profile.*)` - A non-capturing group matching:

    - `JVM=(?<JvmName>\S+)`:
    - `JVM=` - a `JVM=` substring
    - `(?<JvmName>\S+)` - Group `JvmName`: 1+ non-whitespace chars
    - `|` - or
    - `(?<JvmName>\S+)` - Group `JvmName`: 1+ non-whitespace chars
    - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
    - `profile` - the word `profile`
    - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.
- `)` -  end of the `Description` group.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation!